# Python strings and integers to write to file?

Tags: python, types

I'm new to Python, so I'm not sure how I should do this.

I have a list of strings to write to a file. Each string needs to be preceded by a 32bit integer equal to the length of the string.

I need to have all the data that's going to be written to the file before I write it to the file. In C#, I would store everything in a byte array before writing, but I have no clue what to do in Python. Should I use a list, or is there a better data type? How should the information be stored?

edit: an example of what it would look like is:

00 00 00 04 74 65 73 74

the four bytes of an integer in big endian, followed by the string.

Comment: You need to store the data in text, or binary form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lambda expressions to easily create a new list according to the strings and your formatting requirements, like:

```
strings = ['abc', 'abcde', 'abcd', 'abcdefgh']
outputs = map(lambda x: "%d %s" % (len(x), x), strings) # ['3 abc', '5 abcde', '4 abcd', '8 abcdefgh']
f = open("file.out", 'w')
data = '\n'.join(outputs) # Concat all strings in list, separated by line break
f.write(data)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

If you data is stored in the list named 'data' and you want your output to go to a file named 'data.out' the following code will accomplish this:

```
data = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'complicated and long', 'test']

with open('data.out', 'w') as outfp:
    for d in data:
        outfp.write('%4d %s\n' %(len(d), d))
```

yields:

```
  4 this
  2 is
  1 a
 20 complicated and long
  4 test
```

as output in file 'data.out'. Note that the '4' in %4d helps line up the numbers with leading spaces so that the come out formatted nicely.

Alternatively, if you want the ASCII integer values for the characters:

```
with open('data.out', 'w') as outfp:
    for d in data:
       outfp.write('%4d %s\n' %(len(d), ' '.join([str(ord(i)) for i in d])))
```

and you will get

```
  4 116 104 105 115
  2 105 115
  1 97
 20 99 111 109 112 108 105 99 97 116 101 100 32 97 110 100 32 108 111 110 103
  4 116 101 115 116
```

Answer (score 0):

This makes a big string with all the data, as you requested:

```
>>> l = ["abc", "defg"]
>>> data = '\n'.join("%d %s" % (len(x), x) for x in l)
>>> data
3 abc
4 defg
```

Then write it to the file like this:

```
f = open("filename", "w")
f.write(data)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a list of strings stored in `list_of_strings` and you have a file open for writing as `file_handle`. Proceed somewhat as follows (untested)

```
for line in list_of_strings:
    length_of_string = len(line)
    line = str(length_of_string) + " " + line
    file_handle.write(line)
```

Comment: Note: @dhg's answer is shorter and more Pythonic. I've written it "longhand" for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary would be acceptable. Something like:

```
strings = ['a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'aaaa'] #you'd get these
data = dict() #stores values to be written.
for string in strings:
    length = len(string)
    data.update({string: length})
#this is just a check, you would do something similar to write the values to a file.
for string, length in data.items():
    print string, length
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion, I should have included how I needed the bytes of the integer, and not just the integer before the string.

I ended up with something like:

```
import struct

output=''
mystr = 'testing str'
strlen = len(mystr)
output += struct.pack('>i',strlen) + mystr
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing the data in a list should be fine. The lengths can be calculated when you're writing the file. The tricky part is writing them as binary instead of ascii.

To work with binary data you'll probably want to use the [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module. It's pack function will let you convert the lengths of the strings to their binary representations. Since it returns a string you can easily combine it with the strings you want to output.

The example below seemed to work with Python 2.7

```
import struct
strings = ["a", "ab", "abc"]

with open("output.txt", "wb") as output:
    for item in strings:
        output.write("{0}{1}".format(struct.pack('>i', len(item)), item))
```